# Can we update data in function,php in theme file editor?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am working on a gold rate wordpress site. I've written the following code.Actually i made some variables holding values after that i created the shortcodes for those variables but the code is not running

```
// Function to get gold prices
function get_gold_price($key) {
    $transient_key = 'gold_price_' . $key;

    // Try to get the value from transient
    $price = get_transient($transient_key);

    // If transient doesn't exist, set a default value
    if (false === $price) {
        $default_values = array(
            'tola24k'   => 150000,
            'tola22k'   => 150000,
            'tola18k'   => 150000,
            'gr24k'     => 150000,
            'gr22k'     => 150000,
            'gr18k'     => 150000,
            'gr10_24k'  => 150000,
            'gr10_22k'  => 150000,
            'gr10_18k'  => 150000,
        );

        // Set the default value
        $price = $default_values[$key];

        // Save the default value in transient
        set_transient($transient_key, $price, DAY_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    return $price;
}

// Shortcode to display gold price
function gold_price_shortcode($atts) {
    $key = $atts['type']; // 'tola24k', 'tola22k', etc.
    $price = get_gold_price($key);

    return esc_html($price);
}
add_shortcode('gold_price', 'gold_price_shortcode');

// Create a settings page
function gold_prices_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Gold Prices Settings</h2>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
            settings_fields('gold_prices_options');
            do_settings_sections('gold_prices_options');
            submit_button('Save Settings');
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Register settings and add fields
function gold_prices_settings_init() {
    register_setting('gold_prices_options', 'tola24k');
    register_setting('gold_prices_options', 'tola22k');
    // Add more fields for other variables

    add_settings_section('gold_prices_section', 'Gold Prices Settings', '__return_false', 'gold_prices_options');

    add_settings_field('tola24k_field', '24K Tola Price', 'gold_prices_field_callback', 'gold_prices_options', 'gold_prices_section', array('label_for' => 'tola24k'));
    add_settings_field('tola22k_field', '22K Tola Price', 'gold_prices_field_callback', 'gold_prices_options', 'gold_prices_section', array('label_for' => 'tola22k'));
    // Add more fields for other variables
}
add_action('admin_init', 'gold_prices_settings_init');

// Field callback function
function gold_prices_field_callback($args) {
    $option_name = $args['label_for'];
    $option_value = get_option($option_name);
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo esc_attr($option_name); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr($option_name); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($option_value); ?>" />
    <?php
}

// Add a menu item to the admin menu
function gold_prices_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Gold Prices Settings',
        'Gold Prices',
        'manage_options',
        'gold_prices_settings',
        'gold_prices_settings_page'
add_action('admin_menu', 'gold_prices_menu_page');
    );
}
```

Site: [FindGoldRate](https://findgoldrate.com)

1.I checked the syntax many times but it is not working.
2. Is it fine to update data in function.php in themefile editor.

Comment: Do you need the shortcode to do anything? If so, where are you adding the shortcode itself? You are only registering the shortcode. You don’t seem to actually use it.